# Setting up an IPSec VPN with Cisco ASDM

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I am trying to set up a VPN remote access with a Cisco ASDM 6.4 for ASA 5505 Version 8.2(5).

In order to set up the VPN I followed [this steps](http://www.databasemart.com/HowTo/Cisco_VPN_Remote_Access_Setup_ASA5500.aspx). After this steps my info look like this:

```
VPN Tunnel Interface: outside
PPP authentication: MS-CHAP-V1 MS-CHAP-V2
IPsec authentication uses pre-shared key: MyKey
Tunnel Group Name: DefaultRAGroup
Default Group Policy: DefaultRAGroup
User authentication using local user database
New users created in the local database: MyUser
Pool of IP addresses for VPN clients: VPN-Pool (10.0.0.10 - 10.0.0.19)
IKE policy Encryption / Authentication / Diffie-Hellman Group: 3DES /SHA/Group 2
Internal network elements expesed to remote VPN users without NAT: any
Split tunneling: disabled
Perfect Forwards Secrecy (PFS): disabled
```

Then I tested the VPN using a Cisco VPN Client. In the VPN client I use this info:

```
Host: The public IP where I want to connect
User: DefaultRAGroup
Pass: MyKey
```

When I try to connect I get this message:

```
the remote peer is no longer responding reason 412
```

In the firewall I found that the 500 UDP port was closed and it was blocking those packages. I open that UDP Port but I am still getting that message.

Any advice to solve this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: What firewall is in front of your VPN endpoint?

Comment: In the endpoint I have a router Linksys E25000

Comment: Ah.  The thing is, IPsec relies on protocol 50, which runs directly atop IP..  So the chances are, that your Linksys isn't allowing protocol 50 traffic through the router.